# Paypal adaptive shows error when settingup the options

Tags: paypal

Whenever i use Paypal adaptive default SDK for setting options to show item details it just show an error. Please see screenshot. 
CAN ANYONE HELP?

[image]

Comment: Please don't link code in images. Add it directly in the question.

Comment: ok, sorry i will take care of this next time. But can you help me with the question please?